# What is the probability that a third bit does not have to be inspected to find majority?

Tags: probability

I was trying to design a randomized algorithm for computing the majority of 3 bits such that no matter what the values were, the probability of not having to check the 3rd value was **at least** 1/3.

The answer seems to be to check 2 bits in random order and if they are the same output the majority, o.w. check the 3rd bit.

This seems to be at least 1/3 but I couldn't figure out why in a rigorous matter. Isn't the probability exactly 1/2? Once you write out the tree?

Isn't this tree correct:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bits are $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ each, the chance that the second bit you check matches the first is $1/2$, which is the chance you do not have to check the third bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ross Millikan's answer is quite elegant.   We can also take the long way:

---

There are two cases: (A) all bits are the same (B) one bit is different.   Assuming$^\ast$ bits are `1` or `0` with equal probability, then $\mathsf P(A)= \frac 2{8}, \mathsf P(B) = \frac{6}{8}$.   If we test two bits at random, the result we want is (C) both bits are the same (and so we know the majority).

Clearly $\mathsf P(C\mid A)=1$, and $\mathsf P(C\mid B)=\tfrac 1 3$.  Why?

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C) & = \mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(C\mid A)+\mathsf P(B)\cdot\mathsf P(C\mid B) \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 4\cdot 1 + \tfrac 3 4 \cdot\tfrac 1 3 \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 2\end{align}$

---

PS: $\ast$ *Check your assumptions.*   What if the bits are independently the value they should be with probability $p$?